# Why does deserialized JSON array return null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization, deserialization

I have a string stream returning `JSON` data from and API that looks like this:

```
"{\"Recs\": 
[
   {\"EID\":\"F67_24_6\",\"ReturnPeriod\":\"1\",\"GageStation\":\"NA\"}, 
   {\"EID\":\"T67_24_6\",\"ReturnPeriod\":\"2.37\",\"GageStation\":\"Magueyes Island\"}, 
   {\"EID\":\"R67_24_6\",\"ReturnPeriod\":\"1\",\"GageStation\":\"50147800\"}
]}"
```

I am trying to deserialize it to return this:

```
{"Recs":[
          {"EID":"F67_24_6","ReturnPeriod":"1","GageStation":"NA"}, 
          {"EID":"T67_24_6","ReturnPeriod":"2.37","GageStation":"Magueyes Island"},     
          {"EID":"R67_24_6","ReturnPeriod":"1","GageStation":"50147800"}
]}
```

I am using these public classes to structure the return:

```
public class New_Events_Dataset
{
    public string EID { get; set; }
    public string ReturnPeriod { get; set; }
    public string GageStation { get; set; }

}

public class NewRootObject
{
    public List<New_Events_Dataset> Reqs { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to apply this later, I basically get a return of `{"Reqs":null}`. What am I doing wrong here?

```
var jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NewRootObject>(strresult);
string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(jsonResponse);
return json;
```

Comment: You have "Reqs" as the name of the public List property in your root object class, is that intended? The name of the corresponding property in the JSON string appears to be "Recs"

Comment: Why are you using `JsonConvert` together with `JavascriptSerialzer`?

Comment: What Net framework are you using? Try using Net Core, the conversion to JSON is automatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename **Reqs** to **Recs** and create default constructor of class and **instantiate Recs list**

```
public class NewRootObject
{
    List<New_Events_Dataset> Recs { get; set; }

    public NewRootObject()
    {
        Recs = new List<New_Events_Dataset>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nicer solution with instantiation of the List property

Comment: Arghhhh! That was totally it! Thanks for the nested NewRootObject function. That worked nicely.

Answer (score 5):

I think Reqs should be Recs:

```
     public class NewRootObject
    {
         public List<New_Events_Dataset> Reqs { get; set; }
    }
```

try:

```
    public class NewRootObject
    {
         public List<New_Events_Dataset> Recs { get; set; }
     }
```